# Haproxy + GSS180E error: ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I've got haproxy (in pfsense) providing https for my netgear GSS180E and can load up the admin login page fine, but when I plug in the password & submit, I keep on getting:

`The webpage at https://habu/login.cgi might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM`

It appears the netgear page maybe using some frames or passing back some headers but not sure if this is related at all.

`

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1`

Could someone help me understand what's going on and how to resolve or troubleshoot this.

Unfortunately the logging doesn't provide anything useful beyond the request going to the login.cgi...

I've tried to enable Forwardfor in haproxy but this didn't make a difference.  Not familiar with this error and none of the stuff I've read makes sense to me.

Comment: If you go on `https://habu/login.cgi` via browser navigation, you get a successful response, but when hitting the POST action to the same URL, it does not work? It's unclear what actions/requests do go back and forth in scenario.

Comment: Yes agreed, unfortunately the switch is a blackbox.  I looked at the html but it just seems to post the form (password) back to login.cgi.  And logs were no help.